# Collecting elements of an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, collections, julia

I want to understand how to be able to collect elements of n by m dimensional array and store them to n vectors of m dimensions. For example I have the following 3 x 2 array and I want to store the pair of each row into a vector.

```
Array1 = [ 1 0; 2 0; 3 0]
```

That gives:

```
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
1  0
2  0
3  0
```

The idea is to make a for loop that in each iteration stores to a 2 dimensional vector the values of the array above.

I am not sure how to do it since the `collect` function will only save elements of the same column from my experiments until now.

How can I store each pair into a vector then?

Comment: would `eachrow` or `eachcol` help here?

Comment: I would have to find the documentation to see if it can help (never used them before).

Comment: It could help but how do I define/save a new vector each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be as simple as `collect(eachrow(Array1))`

```
julia> collect(eachrow(Array1))
3-element Vector{SubArray{Int64, 1, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, true}}:
 [1, 0]
 [2, 0]
 [3, 0]
```

This is short and which is, more importantly, type stable, so it is more performant than `Any[]` solution. But it creates `view` of the underlying `Matrix` which sometimes is not what you want, especially taking into account that Julia is column-oriented, so row views are going to be relatively slow. If that is the case you can go with

```
julia> collect.(eachrow(Array1))
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 0]
 [2, 0]
 [3, 0]
```

which is still very fast.

But you may also consider your usage of this construction. If, for example, all you want is to iterate over rows, then there is no need to collect at all, you can use `eachrow` straightforwardly without intermediate materialization.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a satisfying answer I will post here for future reference.

First I define a list of vectors that can take any values:

```
listV = Any[];
```

Then I create a `for` loop that stores each pair of elements of an array `Array` using `eachrow`:

```
for row in eachrow(Array);
    push!(listV, row);
end
```

This is good enough.

Comment: I ended up using somethin like `Array{Float64}(undef, 1, 2);`

Comment: I deleted my comment, above yours @Marion, because it was incorrect. But, `Array{Float64}(undef, 1, 2)` doesn't make sense either. You could use `Vector{Vector{eltype(Array1)}}(undef, size(Array1, 1))`. But you really should use @AndrejOskin's solution, it is definitely the most idiomatic and elegant.